# How to solve this trigonometric equation $\cos(\theta +20) = -0.74$

Tags: trigonometry

Hi my question is what approach i should use in order to solve this $\cos(\theta +20) = -0.74$?

### and why do we get rid of the negative sign when solving basis angle?

Here is my working

$\cos(\theta +20) = -0.74$

Then, $\alpha+20 = \arccos (0.74)$, to find the basis angle. After I plugged into the calculator and got $42.3$,  I subtract $20$ from $42.3$ to solve for $\theta$ which is $22.3$. $\theta = 42.3 -20 = 22.3$

Since $\cos$ is negative, the angle is at 2nd and 4th quadrant. So I solve for the angle $180-22.3=157.7$ and $180+22.3=202.3$

But all of this is wrong can someone explain? I think it is my approach that got me wrong, but I am unsure.

Comment: $20$ is probably not degrees.

Comment: Also remember that the equation actually has an infinite number of solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos(\theta+20) = -0.74$$

$$\theta+20 = \arccos (-0.74)$$

Recall the range of $\arccos x$ is $0 \leq x \leq 180$.

$$\begin{cases}
Quadrant \space II \implies \theta+20 = \arccos(-0.74) \implies \theta = \arccos(-0.74)-20\\
\
\\
Quadrant \space III \implies \theta+20 = 360-\arccos(-0.74) \implies \theta = 360-\arccos(-0.74)-20
\end{cases}$$

Finally, solve for $\theta$.

For the angle in the second quadrant:

$$\theta = \arccos(-0.74)-20 \approx 137.73-20 \approx 117.73$$

For the angle in the third quadrant:

$$\theta = 360-\arccos(-0.74)-20 \approx 360-137.73-20 \approx 202.27$$

Remember that angles repeat infinitely, so each angle repeats after $360°$. If the question asks for angles in the domain $0 \leq \theta \leq 360$, your answer is complete.

If, however, you’re asked for a complete set of solutions, you have to add in $\color{blue} {360n}$ for all $\color{blue}{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$.

$$\theta \approx 117.73+360n$$

$$\theta \approx 202.27+360n$$

By changing the order and signs, you reached an incorrect answer. Try to avoid doing that and you’ll be fine with these types of questions.

Comment: Thank you. I am actually preferred not to change the signs ie the negative sign and alpha symbol, but my teacher wanted me to use alpha to represent the basis angle which required to take away the negative sign

Comment: Good, I get your point. The reason you got the wrong answer using that method was that you calculated for $\theta$ first. You’re supposed to calculate the total angle, and then find $\theta$. Using your way, we can do the following: $$\arccos(0.74) \approx 42.27$$ Our total angle ($\theta+20$) is about $42.27°$. The total angle is in quadrants $2$ and $3$. Thus, for the second quadrant: $$\theta+20 \approx 180-42.27 \implies \theta+20 \approx 137.73 \implies \theta \approx 117.73$$ For the third: $$\theta+20 \approx 180+42.27 \implies \theta+20 \approx 222.27 \implies \theta \approx 202.27$$

Comment: So basically, you find the values for $\theta+20$, or rather, the entire angle, first. Then, you find $\theta$ for both situations. You used the reverse process, which got the signs mixed up.

Comment: awesome thanks for helping out! But I have 1 more question, using the current way you have showed me, i tried in one of the questions and i have obtained a negative answer. What does this mean and how do i proceed? $tan(\theta-50)=-1.7$, solve for $\theta$ and i have got $-9.5$. Can you please help? Thank you and sorry

Comment: @Tfue $$\tan(\theta-50) = -1.7$$ $$\theta-50 = \arctan(-1.7)$$ Recall the range of $\arctan x$ is $-\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$. So, the angle given will will be in the the fourth quadrant. But, tangent is also negative in the second quadrant. For the first case, $$\theta-50 = \arctan(-1.7) \implies \theta = \arctan(-1.7)+50 \implies \theta \approx -9.53446 \approx 350.46554$$ For the second case, $$\theta-50 = 180+\arctan(-1.7) \implies \theta = 180+\arctan(-1.7)+50 \implies \theta \approx 170.46554$$

Comment: So yes, you got one of the solutions correctly. Don't freak out if you get a negative angle. For any $-\theta$, the angle can be rewritten as $360-\theta$. Also, as I mentioned, the domain of $\arctan x$ function is $-\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, so the angle returned by the calculator will be in the fourth quadrant. A negative angle is often returned. (For example, $-10°$ rather than $350°$.) If you subtract its absolute value from $360°$ and get a value satisfying $-270° < \theta \leq 360°$, it's all fine.

Comment: Also, as a final note, $\tan x$ is periodic and repeats every $180°$. If the question asks for a general solution, you must add in $\color{blue}{360n}$ for all $\color{blue}{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$. So, you get the following solutions:
$$\theta \approx 350.46554+360n$$
$$\theta \approx 170.46554+360n$$
But if you notice, $350.46554°$ and $350.46554°$ themselves are $$180°$$ apart, so all midpoints will also be covered. Hence, the two solutions can be compressed into one:
$$\theta \approx 170.46554+180n$$
Hence the original point that $\tan x$ is periodic and repeats every $180°$.

Comment: Wow whoever you are thank you everything you have taught me! However, there is stuff I am still unsure about(sorry), such as the $arctan$ domain (or is it range? idk). So you said the $arctan$ domain is $-90<x<90$, does that mean that $x$ is between anticlockwise quadrant 1 and clockwise quadrant 4? With that said so everytime I obtained a negative answer, all I am required to do is just +360?

Comment: @Tfue No problem! I meant range, accidentally wrote domain. Since the range of $\tan x$ is all real numbers, the domain of $\arctan x$ is also all real numbers.

Comment: Also, yes, if your angle is negative, it is always better to add $360$ because positive angles are preferred. You may want to accept the answer if it was helpful too. :-)

Comment: Thank you again! So overall, if i use your method ie (not finding the reference angle), it will not always give you the reference angle but the angle in the range? Which in this case i have obtained $-9.5$, so this is NOT a reference angle right? Or this IS a reference angle but only omitting the negative sign? And my last question (im so sorry), from what you said $-180$ is exact same as $180$, as well as -88.6 is also same as 271.4 Sorry and thank you from my mum and me

Comment: Calculators will only give the angle in the range. I think it would help you out if you knew the domain and range of all six trig functions and their inverses. $$\sin x \implies -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \implies \vert y\vert \leq 1$$ $$\cos x \implies 0 \leq x \leq \pi \implies \vert y\vert \leq 1$$ $$\tan x \implies -\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2} \implies y \in \mathbb{R}$$ These are for the normal trig functions.

Comment: For reciprocal functions: $$\csc x \implies -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}; x\neq 0 \implies \vert y\vert \geq 1$$ $$\sec x \implies 0 \leq x \leq \pi; x\neq \frac{\pi}{2} \implies \vert y\vert \geq 1$$ $$\cot x \implies -\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2}; x\neq 0 \implies y \in \mathbb{R}$$ For inverses, switch domain and range. This might seem like a bit too much to grasp, but if you write it out and think about it, it all becomes clear. (Yes, $180 = -180$ and $271.4 = -88.6$.)

Comment: Thank you for the info, so ie let say we have $arcsin (-0.5)$ it would give me $-30$ since this is in the range. and since this is a negative angle, I just have to plus $360$ to it which means that the first solution is $330$. But since sin is negative then the second solution is located at quadrant 3 right? But how do i find the second solution? I assume the second solution would be $360-150$ then is this correct? (my last question i promise!)

Comment: Yes, the calculator gives $-30°$ as the angle. To get the angle in the third quadrant, add the absolute value to $180°$, thus getting $210°$. As a hint, you can always use the angle in the first quadrant to get the angles in other quadrants. The first quadrant angle here is $30°$, which corresponds to $150°$, $210°$, and $330°$ in the other three quadrants. (At least that’s how I always think about it.) But always remember this applies to the whole angle, not to a part of it. That could get the signs mixed up (like what happened for your first question).

Comment: Wow Thanks so much, but unfortunately i have 1 more question :( sorry. I am currently doing this problem $sin\theta=0$ in the range of 0 or equal to 360 or equal.So, i solved for $\theta$ which i obtained 2 solutions which are $0$ and $180$ BUT this is not completely right! I apprently there is 1 more solutions which is 360! But how?

Comment: Haha no problem, I'm fine answering questions. Technically, $0°$ and $360°$ are the same. (The simplest and most complete solution would be $180n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. This would mean all integer multiples of $180°$ are part of the solution. (Also, do you always work with degrees? Usually radians are preferred, at least from what I've seen.)

Comment: Yes sir i worked with degrees. So, does that mean i have 3 solutions? and when i have $0$ as my solution, i must include $360$ as well? What are  $180n$ for all $n$ E thingy and Z thingy?

Comment: I think it's better to include $360°$ in the solution since the domain given is usually $0 \leq x \leq 360$. $180n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is another way of saying "all multiples of $180°$ are in the answer". (There are infinite solutions in reality.) $$...-720°, -540°, -360°, -180°, 0°, 180°, 360°, 540°, 720°, ...$$ Now whether or not you include that statement depends on what domain the question gives. If it asks for all solutions in the domain $0 \leq x \leq 360$, you don't include it. If it asks for a complete set of solutions, however, you have to include it.

Answer (score 1):

In general we have that in degrees for $x\in[0,360°]$

$$\cos x = y \implies x=\arccos y \quad \lor \quad x=360°-\arccos y$$

therefore

$$\cos(\theta +20°) = -0.74 \implies \theta +20°=\arccos (-0.74) \quad \lor \quad \theta +20°=2\pi-\arccos (-0.74)$$

Check that the calculator is set to give the result in degree.

Comment: Thanks and what do i do when i got a negative angle?

Comment: Working in degrees we obtain [$\arccos(-0.74)= 137.7$](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccos%28-0.74%29) then $\theta=157.7$ and $\theta=360-157.7=202.3$ are both solutions (when we set $\theta\in[0,360]$) and more in general any $\theta=\pm 157.7+360k$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ is a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all angles are in degrees, you should avoid strange switches in the sign.

With a calculator, $\arccos(-0.74)=137.7$, so the solutions are
$$
\theta+20=137.7+360k
$$
or
$$
\theta+20=-137.7+360k
$$
The solutions in the range $[0,360]$ are therefore $137.7-20=117.7$ or $-137-20+360=202.3$.

On the other hand, if angles are measured in radians,
$$
\theta+20=\arccos(-0.74)+2k\pi=2.404+2k\pi
$$
or
$$
\theta+20=-\arccos(-0.74)+2k\pi=-2.404+2k\pi
$$
Thus
$$
\theta=-20+\arccos(-0.74)+2k\pi
$$
or
$$
\theta=-20-\arccos(-0.74)+2k\pi
$$
For the solutions in the range $[0,2\pi]$ you have to choose $k=6$ in the first case and $k=8$ in the second case, obtaining
$$
1.253\qquad\text{or}\qquad 2.729
$$